# Schengen German Visa refusal - Economic Rootage are not sufficently proved

Tags: visas, visa-refusals, schengen-visas, proof-provenance-of-funds

i got 2nd time Visa refusal with almost same reason. but 2nd time it was only one reason "i didnt succeed to demonstrate the willingness to return to home country - the economic rootage in india could not be proved sufficiently/credibly show."

i have proper invitation letter from german family and from my side i showed almost everything(employment contract,pay slip,bank statement, supporting letter from my father , says i am the only son and taking care of family and property, property paper , my father bank statement) .

i am confused now , what they want me to have now ? i dnt own a house , i just have a job . how can i show them exactly my economic rootage. ??

please help me with this problem.

Comment: What on earth would you hope to achieve by attaching a "supporting letter" from your father and _your father's bank statement_ if in the same breath you're also apparently trying to claim you're economically self-sufficient? That doesn't add up, and if something doesn't add up for a visa officer ...